# Why is this element being partially highlighted on hover?

Tags: hover, image, html

I am working on a page right now containing two buttons.  The buttons are a combination of a span, with the button title, surrounded by images of two half circles:

```
<td align="right">
<a href="#" title="Reset" onclick="resetForm();">
        <img src="images/btnBlueL.gif"><span style="background-image:url('images/btnBlueM.gif');color:white;font-weight:bold;height:22px;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;">
         Reset
         </span><img src="images/btnBlueR.gif">
    </a>

     <a href="#" title="Clear all fields" onclick="clearForm()">
         <img src="images/btnBlueL.gif"><span style="background-image:url('images/btnBlueM.gif');color:white;font-weight:bold;height:22px;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;">
          Clear
         </span><img src="images/btnBlueR.gif">
      </a>
```

When I hover over a button, a very small red line appears to the bottom right of the button.  This is in all browsers. It looks like it is partially highlighting the "a" element, but only for a few pixels.  Has anyone seen anything like this? How did you get it to go away?

http://jsfiddle.net/jmlane/VHFwB/

Comment: Please post a minimal http://jsfiddle.net test-case as well as the inline code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Link has no CSS applied:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a img{
    border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a border. Try this CSS rule to remove the border from hyperlinks:

```
a {
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are sometimes unnecessary borders added, so I'd use the following lines in my CSS:

```
a { border: 0; }
img { border: 0; display: block; }
```

Images by default are inline. And avoid having inline styles! :)